# Is it possible to run stateful apps on google application engine standard

Tags: google-app-engine

GAE standard provides an application engine (i.e. no docker) for different programming languages. If I write such an application, would it lose its state when the instance it is running on is changed?

Even when using manual scaling (i.e. the instance is not shut down, even when it is idle), google might need to shut it down (and thus switch the instance my application is running on). E.g. when the instance experiences an error or it needs to be restarted for maintenance purposes.

Is the state then automatically perserved and the application still running on the next instance? Or do I have to write a shutdown-hook, storing the state somewhere and loading it again somehow at startup time?

P.S: State in this case just meens session-state - all underlying data is stored in a database

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained what you mean by "state", but I'm pretty sure that whatever you mean, the answer is no.  You'll need to store the state somewhere and later retrieve it.

For example, anything written to the local filesystem is gone when a new instance starts up.

Comment: Specifically I mean (serializable) server-state of a session of a webapplication running in Vaadin (or whatever webframework that holds session state at the server-side)

Comment: I have no idea idea what Vaadin is.  Where do you store it server side?  Memory, database, redis?  Please update your question.